# Why is it not correct when constructor is called recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion, constructor

This is leetcode 341. When I write like this, it is correct:

```
class NestedIterator {
public:
    vector<int> flatted;
    int current=0;
    NestedIterator(vector<NestedInteger> &nestedList) {
        flatten(nestedList);
    }
    
    void flatten(vector<NestedInteger> &nestedList)
    {
        for(NestedInteger i:nestedList)
        {
            if(i.isInteger())
                flatted.push_back(i.getInteger());
            else
                flatten(i.getList());
        }
    }
    
    int next() {
        current++;
        return flatted[current-1];
    }
    
    bool hasNext() {
        if(current<flatted.size())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

But, if I write it like this, it is not correct:

```
class NestedIterator {
public:
    vector<int> flatted;
    int current=0;
    NestedIterator(vector<NestedInteger> &nestedList) {
        for(NestedInteger i:nestedList)
        {
            if(i.isInteger())
                flatted.push_back(i.getInteger());
            else
                NestedIterator(i.getList());
        }
    }
};
```

The only difference is that in method 2, I call the constructor recursively. Why is it not correct?

Comment: *"I call the constructor recursively*" No, you don't. The code `NestedIterator(i.getList());` creates a new temporary iterator, that is then immediately destroyed. Constructors are different from ordinary functions.

Comment: It is because a constructor is not a normal function/method. Add another method (a protected or private one) that your constructor calls to do the dirty work.

Comment: @BoP  Thank you guys. I still don't understand. _"creates a new temporary iterator, that is then immediately destroyed"_ Does it mean each time the constructor is called, it creates a new variable and operates on that variable? Why?

Comment: Your code doesn't pass because `NestedIterator(i.getList());` creates its own list and when it's done, the object goes out of scope and nothing happens with the current iterator

Comment: There is no way in a C++ program to "call a constructor". It is only ever invoked automatically when an object is created. `NestedIterator(...)` is an expression creating a temporary.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Thank you. I thought constructor is just a function that is called when I define a variable. The constructor initializes that variable. In my case, what does the constructor do? Each time the constructor is called, it operates on a different variable?

Comment: When you write NestedIterator(…) you aren’t calling a constructor.  Rather you are declaring a NestedIterator object (similar to if you wrote int() to declare an int).  The compiler then inserts a call to the constructor on that just-declared object, but since the object is an anonymous temporary object, it is destroyed again almost immediately afterwards.

Comment: *"This is leetcode 341"* -- this is insufficient for describing what the correct/desired behavior is.

Comment: Thank you guys, all of you. :)  I think I get the point finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the iterator you create below the loop is not working because it has its own list that it populates and since you never keep any reference to it, after it is finished, it goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Try this instead:

```
class NestedIterator {
public:
    vector<int> flatted;
    int current=0;
    NestedIterator(vector<NestedInteger> &nestedList) {
        for(NestedInteger i:nestedList)
        {
            if(i.isInteger())
                flatted.push_back(i.getInteger());
            else {
                auto iter = NestedIterator(i.getList());
                this->flatted.insert(this->flatted.end(), iter.flatted.begin(), iter.flatted.end()); // here we copy the vector from this iterator
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The goal above is to copy the vector from the temporary iterator, into the current one

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. I change the last statement to `this->flatted.insert(this->flatted.end(), iter.flatted.begin(), iter.flatted.end());`